# YouTube API http request unity workaround

Tags: c#, http, youtube, youtube-api, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to find a workaround to the unity problems with OAuth, since I'm currently working with the YouTube API v3, and am in need of getting a list of videos and their IDs of a certain category (sports, cars, music, etc...).

I'm wondering if there's a way of manually inputting the http request, and preferably to return it with a regular snippet output. Here's what I've tried so far: (the commented part was the implementation using the regular snippet method)

Apparently unity isn't that compatible with OAuth and so the queries don't work, so, I'm trying to do a HTTP request manually, which I obtained from

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=50&regionCode=PT&type=video&videoCategoryId=10&_h=3&

Is there any way I can set the snippet query by the one in the 'http' variable?

```
public static Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data.SearchListResponse  GetCategoryRelated(string category)
{
        string httpRequest = "GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&regionCode=PT&type=video&videoCategoryId=10&key=MyKey";

        var searchListRequest = ytService.Search.List("snippet");


        //var searchListRequest = ytService.Search.List(httpRequest);
        //searchListRequest.VideoCategoryId = category;
        //searchListRequest.Type ="video";   
        //searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
        //var videoCatagories = ytService.VideoCategories.List("snippet");
        //videoCatagories.RegionCode = "PT";
        //var result = videoCatagories.Execute();

        var searchListResponse = searchListRequest.Execute();

        return searchListResponse;
        //return result;
}
```